Изъять json файл с сайта, не имея доступ к api
Хочу запарсить букмекерскую сайт https://betboom.ru/esport?pageRoute=timeline&type=upcoming
А именно коэффициенты, команды и прочее. Черех "просмотр кода элемента" -> network нашел нужный json файл, но при переходе по ссылке (https://api-bifrost.oddin.gg/main/bifrost/query) даёт ошибку 401. Как я понял мне нужно получить доступ, но навряд ли мне его дадут. То есть прям с api я не могу получить информацию, но могу ли я забрать этот json прямо с самого сайта, с которого делался запрос к этому api. Если могу, то подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом я могу это реализовать через пайтон (или через любой другой язык) ? Прошу подсказать хотя бы направление, в которое мне нужно капать в поисках решения. 

наверняка на сайте выполняется POST запрос к api, а вы (открывая в браузере) делаете GET

Если сайт имеет доступ к api, значит вы через тот же самый network можете посмотреть, каким образом он получил доступ к api

На там сайте вызов к API происходит через js скрипт https://betboom.ru/site_js/group-ib/main__fca81129_597_1806.js ,  там же можно посмотреть как именно происходит запрос. Скорее всего там и есть ответ. Правда код понять там сложновато)

не хватает мне опыта, чтобы разобраться в этой каше. В любом случае, подскажите пожалуйста, могу ли я получить JSON файл, не прибегая к использованию api ?

пробуйте селенимум, раз не хватает опыта
